How to transfer the focus on a subview to the entire root view by modifying the settings of the layout file in Android
When my Android app was adapted to the TV remote control, I added two groups of buttons in the layout file. I tried to let them get the focus. The left and right keys of the remote control can switch the focus to different buttons. I hope to move the focus to the rootView with the up key. I used nextFocusDown="@id/btn_left_previous". When the down key is pressed, the focus is transferred from the root to "@id/btn_left_previous". But when I want to transfer the focus from the button to the root through the up key nextFocusUp=@+id/selector_bg", it fails. The following is my layout file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/selector_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/btn_left_previous">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_content_window"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_hide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/player_title_height"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_hide"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_connected_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/player_title_height"
        android:background="@color/colorItemBg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/px10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/px50"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPlayerTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/player_title_textsize" />

        <com.kgzn.castscreen.screenshare.widget.StrokeTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_dev_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/px30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPlayerTitle"
            android:textSize="@dimen/player_title_textsize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/music_picture"
        layout="@layout/music_picture"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/view_ksharemediacontroller"
        layout="@layout/view_ksharemediacontroller"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/view_mymediacontroller"
        layout="@layout/view_mymediacontroller"
        android:visibility="gone" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/px228"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/px19"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/px19"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/group_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_left_esc, btn_left_next, btn_left_previous" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_previous"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_previous"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_left_next"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/btn_right_next"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_next"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/px9"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/px9"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_left_esc"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_left_previous"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_left_esc"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_esc"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_left_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/btn_right_esc" 
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/px228"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/px19"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/px19"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/group_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="btn_right_esc, btn_right_previous, btn_right_next" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_esc"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_esc"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_right_previous"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/btn_left_esc" 
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_previous"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/px9"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/px9"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_previous"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/btn_right_next"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_right_esc"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_right_next"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/px70"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/px70"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/selector_next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_right_previous"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/btn_left_previous" 
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/selector_bg" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Finally, I achieved my expected effect by binding key listeners to each control in the Java code, as shown below. I just want to know why my changes to the layout file did not achieve the expected effect.
View.OnKeyListener viewKeyListener = new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && groupRightPpt.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    Log.d("lyk", "upupup");
                    rootView.requestFocus();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

btnLeftPrevious.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);
        btnLeftNext.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);
        btnLeftEsc.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);
        btnRightEsc.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);
        btnRightPrevious.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);
        btnRightNext.setOnKeyListener(viewKeyListener);

